# What is the derivation that shows Haskell's \x -> (x, x) equivalent to join (,)?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

According to `pointfree`:

```
\x -> (x, x)
```

is equivalent to:

```
join (,)
```

What is the derivation that shows this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Look at the type signatures:

```
\x -> (x, x) :: a -> (a, a)

(,)          :: a -> b -> (a, b)

join         :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

It should be noted that `((->) r)` is an instance of the `Monad` typeclass. Hence, on specializing:

```
join         :: (r -> r -> a) -> (r -> a)
```

What `join` does for functions is apply the given function twice to the same argument:

```
join f x = f x x

-- or

join f = \x -> f x x
```

From this, we can see trivially:

```
join (,) = \x -> (,) x x

-- or

join (,) = \x -> (x, x)
```

Qed.

Answer (score 24):

I like Aadits intuitive answer. Here's how I'd figure it out by reading the source code.

1. I go to [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)
2. I search for [`join`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=join)
3. I [click on `join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join)
4. I click the "source" button to get to [the source code for `join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#join)
5. I see that `join x = x >>= id`
6. So I know that `join (,) = (,) >>= id`
7. I [search for `>>=` on Hoogle and click the link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-)
8. I see that it's part of the monad typeclass, and I know I'm dealing with `(,)` which is a function, so I [click "source" on the `Monad ((->) r)` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-621)
9. I see that `f >>= k = \r -> k (f r) r`
10. Since we have `f = (,)` and `k = id`, we get `\r -> id ((,) r) r`
11. Sooo... new function! `id`! I search for that on Hoogle, and [click through to its source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#id)
12. Turns out `id x = x`
13. So instead of `join (,)` we now have `\r -> ((,) r) r`
14. Which is the same thing as `\r -> (,) r r`
15. Which is the same thing as `\r -> (r,r)`

Never forget that the Haddocks link through to the source code of the library. That's immensely useful when trying to figure out how things work together.

Comment: This is beautiful for beginners. Writing this sort of answers is immensely useful for newcomers.