# Haskell function that accepts function or value, then calls function or returns value

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How can I write a type declaration and function in Haskell that takes either a function (that itself takes no arguments) *or* a value. When given a function it calls the function. When given a value it returns the value.

**[edit]** To give more context, I'm mostly curious how to solve this problem in Haskell without bit twiddling: [Designing function f(f(n)) == -n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731832/interview-question-ffn-n)

Sean

Comment: You can't unless you use (some type isomorphic to) Either so that both types are encapsulated by a single type. What's more, you shouldn't want to: Haskell is not designed to allow you to pass different types to the same function.

Comment: You could also use `const` to pass in the value as a function that ignores its argument.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, I bet there's also some horrifying trick with `OverlappingInstances` and `TypeFamilies` and maybe `DataKinds`.

Comment: @dfeuer I am choosing to restrict myself to what I consider to be reasonable solutions...

Comment: I don't see how your question applies to your edit. You aren't passing a function to a function. A direct translation of the Python solution would work in Haskell.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs forgive me if i'm misunderstanding, but I think the Python version can be called like this `f(f(7))`. Out of pure curiosity I'm just wondering how/if a function in Haskell might be defined to support being called like `f 7` as well as `f f 7` or even `f f f f 7`.

Comment: `f(f(7))` calls `f` with the result of `f(7)`. It never calls `f(f)`. The Haskell versions would be `f (f 7)` and `f (f (f 7))`, not `f f 7`.

Comment: @seanomlor Are you referring to the answer by viraptor? That seems to fit what you're describing and I think that's where this confusion is arising (I assumed you were talking about the accepted answer at first, too). The accepted answer doesn't need that kind of trick.

Comment: @DavidYoung I think my main issue here is that I was just caught up in a complete misunderstanding of Haskell function calls. The solution does not actually ever need to handle a function as an argument. ⊙﹏⊙

Comment: A "function that itself takes no arguments" isn't a thing in Haskell. Without side effects, there is no semantic difference between "a thing that will give me a value when I run it, needing no information" and just having the return value. With laziness, there's not even the operational difference of having already done all the computational work, or not.

Comment: @Ben right about functions without arguments (there's no such thing). However, functions _of no meaningful argument_, `() -> A`, are possible and indeed not quite the same to bare values of type `A`: [normal, lazy-evaluated values](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form) are _memoised_, function results aren't.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, except that the full laziness transformation makes it hard to rely on memoization not happening.

Comment: @leftaroundabout A is denotationally isomorphic to A^1 (this is also generally true of algebraic structures with units and exponents)  but operationally may be different. Of course it's even more different in a strict language, where the transformation A -> A^1 is often used to create a "thunk", taking advantage of their denotational equivalence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm mostly curious how to solve this problem in Haskell without bit twiddling: [Designing function f(f(n)) == -n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731832/interview-question-ffn-n)

That's actually quite easy to solve:

```hs
when :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
when p f x = if p x then f x else x

f :: Integer -> Integer
f = (+) <$> when even negate <*> signum
```

How do we derive this? Consider:

```hs
f (f n) = (-n) -- (0) - from the interview question

f x     = y    -- (1) - assumption

f y     = (-x) -- (2) - from (0) and (1), f (f x) = (-x)

f (-x)  = (-y) -- (3) - from (0) and (2), f (f y) = (-y)

f (-y)  = x    -- (4) - from (0) and (3), f (f (-x)) = x
```

Now, if you see the left hand sides of these equations then you'll notice that there are four cases:

1. `f x`.
2. `f y`.
3. `f (-x)`.
4. `f (-y)`.

Notice that the domain of the function `f` is divided into positive and negative numbers, `x` and `(-x)`, and `y` and `(-y)`. Let's assume that `x` and `y` together form the set of positive numbers and `(-x)` and `(-y)` together form the set of negative numbers.

The set of positive numbers is divided into two [proper](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperSubset.html) [disjoint](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjointSets.html) subsets, `x` and `y`. How do we divide the set of positive numbers into two proper disjoint subsets? Odd and even numbers are a good candidate. Hence, let's assume that `x` is the set of positive odd numbers and `y` is the set of positive even numbers.

Another advantage of using odd and even numbers is that when negated odd numbers remain odd and even numbers remain even. Hence, `(-x)` is the set of negative odd numbers and `(-y)` is the set of negative even numbers.

Now, consider the four cases again. Notice that the sign only changes when the number is even:

1. `f x = y` (sign does not change).
2. `f y = (-x)` (sign changes).
3. `f (-x) = (-y)` (sign does not change).
4. `f (-y) = x` (sign changes).

Hence, we only negate the number when it is even (i.e. `when even negate`).

Next, we need to convert odd numbers into even numbers and vice versa. The easiest way to do so is to add or subtract one from the number. However, care should be taken that the resulting number is not `0`. Consider the special case of `0`:

```hs
f 0    = z    -- (a) - assumption

f z    = (-0) -- (b) - from (0) and (a), f (f 0) = (-0)

f (-0) = (-z) -- (c) - from (0) and (b), f (f z) = (-z)

(-0)   = 0    -- (d) - reflexivity

f (-0) = f 0  -- (e) - from (d)

(-z)   = z    -- (f) - from (a) and (c) and (e)

z      = 0    -- (g) - from (d) and (f)

f 0    = 0    -- (h) - from (a) and (g)
```

Hence, `f n = 0` [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) `n = 0`. So let's consider the neighbors of `0`, `1` and `(-1)`. Both of them are odd numbers. Hence, they are not negated. However, they do need to be converted into an even number (except for `0`). Hence, `1` is converted into `2` and `(-1)` is converted into `(-2)`.

Thus, for odd numbers we simply add the sign of the number to the number itself.

Now, consider even numbers. We know:

```hs
f 1    = 2    -- (A)

f (-1) = (-2) -- (B)
```

Therefore:

```hs
f 2    = (-1) -- (C), from (0) and (A), f (f 1) = (-1)

f (-2) = 1    -- (D), from (0) and (B), f (f (-1)) = 1
```

We know that even numbers are always negated. Hence, `2` first becomes `(-2)` and vice versa. Let the original even number be `n`. Hence, first we `negate n` and then add `signum n` to it:

```hs
evenF n    = negate n    + signum n

evenF 2    = negate 2    + signum 2
           = (-2)        + 1
           = (-1)

evenF (-2) = negate (-2) + signum (-2)
           = 2           + (-1)
           = 1

evenF 0    = negate 0    + signum 0
           = 0           + 0
           = 0
```

Thus, for both the odd case and the even case we add the sign of the original number to `when even negate`. Therefore, `f` is defined as:

```hs
f :: Integer -> Integer
f = (+) <$> when even negate <*> signum
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow! Incredible. Thank you. ʘ‿ʘ

Answer (score 4):

You can't write a function with two different signatures (unless you use typeclasses, but typeclasses are not suitable for this problem). You must solve this in a way that lets you treat both functions and non-function values as the same type. There are two obvious options:

1. Use a sum type.

   ```
   f :: Either (Int -> Char) Char -> Char
   f (Left g) = g 1
   f (Right c) = c
   ```
2. Use `const` to convert your non-function value into a function that ignores its argument:

   ```
   f = ($ 42)
   f chr         --> '*'
   f (const 'a') --> 'a'
   ```

**However, since this is a very unHaskelly thing to ask for, I suspect that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).**

Comment: Definitely XY problem, thanks for all your help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do it like this:

```
data FunctionOrValue a
    = Function (() -> a)
    | Value a

getValue :: FunctionOrValue a -> a
getValue (Function f) = f ()
getValue (Value x) = x
```

However this is a bit silly.

It sounds like you're trying to defer values manually, but since Haskell is lazy, there's not normally a need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

An answer based on the interview question you posted:

```
f n = if (abs fracN) > 1 then 1/fracN else - (1/fracN)
  where
    fracN = realToFrac n
```

The question specified that the input is an int; it did not specify that the result must also be an int.

Edit: if you must return an Int, note that the question allows you to specify a range of possible inputs. I use a limit of 1073741823 (half of the max value of a signed 32-bit int), which allows me to write this:

```
fint :: Int -> Int
fint 0 = 0
fint n = if (abs n) <= rangeVal then n+addend else -(n-addend)
  where
    rangeVal = 1073741823
    negator = if n < 0 then -1 else 1
    addend = negator*rangeVal
```

Comment: This is cool. Curious how you might write this if requirement _was_ Int result?

Comment: You inspired me to look for a solution to `Integer -> Integer` without a range.  It is possible!

Comment: @luqui can you post the solution you found without a range?

Comment: I found the same one as @seanomlor (just expressed a little differently)

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice thing in Haskell (IMHO) is there is no difference between a value and a function without parameter returning a value (thanks to lazyness AND purity). Or if you prefer, every value is in fact a function without parameter which will be evaluated when needed. Therefore there is no need to worry about that type of problem. There is no such thing like `f()`, it's just `f`.

For example, you can write

```
x = 3 :: Int 
f = head [] :: Int -- should blow up but doesn't

head [x, f] -- note that f and x have the same type
> 3  -- doesn't blow up on f, because f is not called

head [f] -- blows up, when trying to print f
```

Comment: Values are not "functions without parameters". That's absolutely wrong. [Values and functions are different things altogether](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30148316/783743). Laziness and referential transparency (purity) are orthogonal concepts to functions and values. Yes, `head []` doesn't blow up because of laziness but that doesn't make it "a function without a parameter" because it is not a function at all. It's an unevaluated expression. Also, `f = ...` is neither a function nor a value. It's just a name binding. Finally, Haskell does have nullary functions. They are simply IO actions. 3=D

Comment: In addition, I don't see how your answer addresses the OP's question at all. Hence, it should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @AaditMShah That's your definition of nullary function which includes side-effect. I agree that technically, "value" are not instance of `(->)` and therefore are not function as such, but neither are `IO` value. There are actions, not function. If you agree that nullary function exists in haskell, then value and nullary function are semantically equivalent : It's the generalisation of `a -> b -> c`  is a function with 2 args, `a -> b`, 1 arg, `a`: 0.

Comment: ... this equivalance is not true in other language, for example in python you can have `x = 3` and `def f(): 3` and they will behave differenty. In Haskell, theres is no equivalent to `def f(): 3`. I think that's what the OP is confused with.